# track logins in appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, decorator

I'm building a groupon-y service to learn app engine. I want to track a list of accounts that log in to the site (using google authentication). What's the best way to do this? Since I use google authentication there's no single point in time where they 'sign up'; they could log in at any url.

Here is what I've tried:

- a force_login function at the start of every single request handler that does a get_or_insert
- i think i could subclass [@login_required](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/utilmodule.html), but i still must remember decorators on all of my request handlers

isn't there a way to just hook right after the login, and register some logic?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a decorator - you'll have to remember to put it in front of any handlers that require login anyway - or you could do it in a base RequestHandler that all your handlers extend (my personal preference), or you could write some WSGI middleware that does it. It's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to execute code immediately after logging in, except, as you said, to remember to do it at the beginning of every handler, or in a decorator on each handler. The decorator sounds like a better option.

Answer (score 0):

How would You write a decorator?

Something Similar to 
`[RequiresAuthentication]` in .net MVC?

```
class Importer(webapp.RequestHandler):
    @RequiresAuthentication
    def get(self):
        pass



def RequiresAuthentication(fn):
    def authorize(self):
        if not users.get_current_user():
            self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
        else:
            return fn(self)
    return authorize
```

I just tested above in the test app and it seemed to work.

After looking at @login_required it doesn't work for post:

```
def login_required(handler_method):
  """A decorator to require that a user be logged in to access a handler.

  To use it, decorate your get() method like this:

    @login_required
    def get(self):
      user = users.get_current_user(self)
      self.response.out.write('Hello, ' + user.nickname())

  We will redirect to a login page if the user is not logged in. We always
  redirect to the request URI, and Google Accounts only redirects back as a GET
  request, so this should not be used for POSTs.
  """
  def check_login(self, *args):
    if self.request.method != 'GET':
      raise webapp.Error('The check_login decorator can only be used for GET '
                         'requests')
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if not user:
      self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
      return
    else:
      handler_method(self, *args)
  return check_login
```